# Is it possible to call BecomeFirstResponder without animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Just a simple question, every time I call BecomeFirstResponder of a UITextField, if no keyboard is on screen, its appears with an animation, Id like to avoid this.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to avoid the keyboard appearing or just it animating on?

Comment: I would be interested in knowing how to prevent the keyboard from appearing at all.

Comment: Pang, that's the answer I was lookign for in that day and I couldnt find, if you write it as an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following link is useful to you.

- [Keyboard Animation Issues When Calling becomeFirstResponder within a Modal View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512502/keyboard-animation-issues-when-calling-becomefirstresponder-within-a-modal-view-c)