# Showing keyboard at the right time iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios7

In iOS 6 I'm used to present keyboard in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [txtField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This way, when navigationController pushes the new viewController, keyboard is already there, animating smoothly from left to right and avoiding bottom-up animation.

In iOS 7 this behavior seems broken.

If I add `[txtField becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewDidLoad`, keyboard appears in the middle of pushing animation, already in its final position: an unpleasant effect!!

I've tried to move `[txtField becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewWillAppear`, but the final result is unchanged.

Do you know a way to get back iOS 6 behavior, pushing the new viewController and the keyboard all together?

EDIT: Using a timer doesn't work either... whatever time delay I set, the keyboard is shown only at the end of pushing animation.

So far, my best try it is to put `[txtField becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Unfortunately, doing so working when pushing viewController but not when popping back (the keyboard doesn't appear).

Comment: Give delay .5 sec using timer in ios 7.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Please, take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 13):

I've managed to extrapolate your workaround in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to force it to work.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    if (![self.textField1 isFirstResponder] && ![self.textField2 isFirstResponder] && ...) {
        [self.textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

This is working for me for both pushing onto the stack, and after dismissing a modal view controller.

Comment: Awesome!.. this was exactly what I needed..  ViewWillAppear is too soon and ViewDidAppear is too late.

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` was the right method for me to use, but I also needed to wrap `becomeFirstResponder` method in to `perform:selector` as follow:  `textView.perform(#selector(becomeFirstResponder), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)`