# Not able to include controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller

I am not able to include the particular controller inside my code but other controllers are included, I included the controller as header but I am not able to include it inside. I attach my code here, I am not able to include IndexPageTableViewController as favoritesViewController?

```
#import "IndexPageTableViewController.h"
#import "FavoritesViewController.h"

-(void) navigateToFavorites
{
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                                         bundle: nil];
if(mainStoryboard)
{
    FavoritesViewController *favorites = (FavoritesViewController *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritesViewController"];
    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance ] popToRootAndSwitchToViewController:favorites withSlideOutAnimation:NO andCompletion:^{
        [self initTableView];
    }];
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not able to include", does it give you an error, if so please post the error information also.

Comment: Do you mean to say you are unable to create an instance "IndexPageTableViewController"? Enna solringa puriayala?

Comment: unknown receiver mainStoryboard is the error

Comment: Are you sure that the name "Main_iPhone" is the right one?

Comment: signal sigabrt error it is not navigating to the IndexPageViewController

Comment: Can you add/post the exact error message? Again, are you sure that the `IndexPageTableViewController` is inside the `Main_iPhone.storyboard`?

Comment: yes I am sure the IndexPageTableViewController is inside the Main_iPhone.storyboard. In the above code instead of FavoritesViewController I used IndexPageTableViewController I am not able to navigate to IndexPageTableViewController alone but I am able to navigate to FavoritesViewController.  The error message is signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comment that you are getting `signal sigabrt error` that means you may not set `FavoritesViewController` as identifier in `interface builder`. you can set `Storyboard ID` under `identity` under `Identity Inspector`. Custom class and storyboard id both are different thing. I think `FavoritesViewController` is your class that you have set from identity inspector. If you want to instantiate storyboard then you have to set `storyboard id` and then you can use that id to instantiate view controller.

Second thing make sure that your storyboard's name is correct and your view controller is within this storyboard. And you have make proper setup if you are using multiple storyboard.

Comment: I solved the issue and now I am facing the issue, how to enable the keyboard when it is navigated to indexPageViewController

Comment: `[yourTexttfield becomeFirstResponder];` call this method on `viewDidload` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: [self.something.searchField becomeFirstResponder]; I applied in viewDidload and viewWillAppear but not working

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023798/showing-keyboard-at-the-right-time-ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023798/showing-keyboard-at-the-right-time-ios7)